# Save posted JSON in grunt server to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, gruntjs

I'm trying to store the json data posted in the grunt server, now I'm receiving the data in a variable and I can make a response with the body of the post. But how could I save this variable into a file in /api directory to work with this data in an angularjs app? I'm new using grunt and angularJS.

Here is my gruntFile:

```
// Generated on 2014-10-20 using generator-angular 0.9.8
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
var jsonFile;

module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

var fs = require('fs');

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var postResponder = function(request, response, next) {
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        console.log(request.method + " " + request.url);
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/text');
        response.statusCode = 200;
        jsonFile = JSON.stringify(request.body);
        response.end(JSON.stringify(request.body));


    } else if (request.method === 'GET') {
        console.log(request.method + " " + request.url);


    } else {
        next();
    }
};



// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-templates');

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    ngtemplates: {
        lformsWidget: {
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/partials',
            src: '{,*/}*.html',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/lforms.tpl.js'
        }
    },

    directivejs: {

    },

    directivecss: {

    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        data: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/data/{,*/}*.js'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9001,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            //hostname: 'localhost',
            hostname: '127.0.0.1',
            livereload: 35731
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect().use('/api', bodyParser.json()),
                        connect().use('/api', postResponder),
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use('/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)

                    ];

                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9002,
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
    },

    protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/protractor/conf.js", // Default config file
            // If keepAlive it true, grunt test finishes with the statement "Done,
            // without errors" even when there are errors.
            //keepAlive: true // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        },
        all: {} // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/test/lforms_testpage.html',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/test/directiveTest.html',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/test/directiveAttrTest.html'
            ],
            ignorePath: /\.\.\//
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                html: {
                    steps: {
                        js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
        }
    },

    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                conservativeCollapse: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                src: ['*.js', '!oldieshim.js'],
                dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
        dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '*.html',
                    'views/{,*/}*.html',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'fonts/*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/images',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                src: ['generated/*']
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                src: 'fonts/*',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function(target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function(target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    //'karma'
    'wiredep',
    'protractor'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    //'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, is using the code grunt.file.write when I receive the post code.

```
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var postResponder = function(request, response, next) {
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        console.log(request.method + " " + request.url);
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/text');
        response.statusCode = 200;
        jsonFile = JSON.stringify(request.body);
        response.end(JSON.stringify(request.body));
        grunt.file.write('./app/data/test.js', jsonFile);


    } else if (request.method === 'GET') {
        console.log(request.method + " " + request.url);


    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

But I accept more and better solutions.